# When does Aurora DB consider either a primary or replica instance as failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I've been reading that Aurora DB will promote a replica as the new primary when a primary instance fails--and also that replicas will be replaced with a new instance if they fail.

I guess my question is on a more basic level than all of this--what does Aurora see to think that an instance (either primary or a replica) has failed? Is it a certain error code or lack of response? Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The RDS infrastructure monitors the instances for "failure" which could be any number of things, probably ranging from an outright hardware fault, to a software crash, to internal operational indicators, some of which are likely not to be even meaningful terms unless you are on the RDS development team.  What are you trying to learn with this question?

Comment: I'd basically like to know when I can expect AWS to take some action, such as promoting a replica to the new primary.